# How to provide input to a python subprocess call that expects filename, rather than variable?

Tags: python, shell, variables, subprocess, pipe

I'm trying to call a shell script (segment.sh) within python.
The syntax that produce correct results at the console is:

```
> ./segment.sh ctb file.txt utf-8 0
```

As can be seen, this shell script expects an text file as input. What I am trying to do is to open up the file and read its content in python (later preferably from an HTML POST form), and somehow pass the variable containing the content to the python subprocess
call.

The following function is not working. But if I just provide a file name such as:

```
Popen(["/bin/bash", "./segment.sh", "ctb", "file.txt", "utf-8", "0"])`
```

then, it will work, but I want to pass the input from a variable. Would you please give me some pointers?

```
def pySegment(text):
    op = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "./segment.sh", "ctb", "utf-8", "0"],
                      stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdin  = subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,                          
                      )
    results = op.communicate(input=text)[0]
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = "./file.txt"
    text = open(filename).read()
    result = pySegment(text)
    print result
```

Comment: If `segment.sh` is actually opening the filename that you give it and reading its contents, and _doesn't support_ reading from standard input, then unfortunately you'll have to either save the text to a file, or modify `segment.sh`. That's one of the idea of Unix programming: make every program capable of functioning like a filter - in other words, have the ability to read from standard input and write to standard output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @voithos. The segment.sh script itself is calling an java program: JAVACMD="java -mx2g -cp $BASEDIR/seg.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -sighanCorporaDict $DATADIR **-testFile $file** -inputEncoding $enc -sighanPostProcessing true $ARGS".

So, I'm not sure if this program can take standard input besides a file. Please advise.

Comment: The same point holds. The Java program that your script is running needs to be able to read from standard input. It seems like you're going against your tools here. Not all programs have been written with standard input/output in mind, unfortunately. But is there a problem with just using the file? Just run `pySegment` on the file instead of on your variable, and then open the segmented file and read it.

Comment: try to pass `-` as a filename. It is a common convention to read from stdin if `-` passed as a filename.

Comment: you could drop `/bin/bash` if `./segment.sh` has `#!/bin/bash` shebang and it is executable (`chmod +x segment.sh`)

Comment: @voithos: Thanks for your advice. Yes, I could run pySegment on the file, but I also want the program to be able to take input from a variable, submitted through a web form, for example. In that case, I have to write those contents into a file and then read it out, which I fear might cause some performance issue. Right?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I tried the - trick, but it doesn't work. I did it like this: ["./segment.sh", "ctb", "-", "utf-8", "0"] Am I doing it right? Thanks for the comment on the shebang line. I removed it and it still works.

Comment: Without shebang you should get '[Errno 8] Exec format error'. You might mean that you've removed '/bin/bash' from `Popen()` call. The `java` program probably doesn't treat `-` as a special name. So you need a temporary file (see `tempfile`) or named pipe as @jcollado suggested.

Comment: @user1172819: Not really - if you aren't getting millions and millions of hits a day, it should be no problem. Besides, you're _calling an external process using a shell script_... Shell scripts aren't prone to high performance. And since you're running it as another process, you'll probably be accessing the file system anyway. So, basically, I don't think writing out the file would be so bad. Why are you using a shell script anyway? Does it do anything other than run `java`? If not, just execute the Java program directly from Python.

Comment: @voithos, thanks for the insights. The shell script was used to run 'java'. Because it's a bit involved, I haven't figured out how to do that in Python. Again, I assume that doing this via a shell than calling 'java' directly would imply a bit performance issue right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe):

```
import os, tempfile, shutil, subprocess

temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
filename = os.path.join(temp_dir, 'file.txt')
text = '<text>'
os.mkfifo(filename)

try:
    subprocess.Popen(('segment.sh', 'ctf', filename, 'utf-8', '0'))
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

The named pipe will offer the same interface of a file without really creating that file as you need.

Comment: `os.mkfifo(filename)` should probably be outside `try/finally`. To avoid collisions `tempfile.mkdtemp()` might be used (with `shutil.rmtree()` afterwards).

Comment: @jcollado Thanks a lot for the code and suggestion of named pipe. This is something new to me. So text = '<text>' is the place I could assign contents to be segmented, right?

Comment: @user1172819 Yes, that's correct. Note also that you can use the pipe as any other file, so you can have as many `write` calls as needed mixed with some processing based on any other input required, that is, you don't need to have everything in a variable before writing.

Comment: @jcollado, YES! The code works. Thanks so much for helping me out. I also want to thank voithos and J.F. Sebastian for your very useful comments. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Not sure if it's appropriate to ask a related question here. But the java-based segmenter need to load a very large (100M) dictionary file and takes 12+ seconds. I wonder if there's any way to speed this up, and most importantly, to avoid load it EVERY time I need to call it. Would you please give me some pointers...

Comment: @aihaiyang I think it would be better to ask that in a separate question.