# How to avoid loading a large file repeatedly?

Tags: java, python, performance, process, persistence

I'm trying to call a Java program (Stanford Chinese Word Segmenter) from within python. The Java program needs to load a large (100M) dictionary file (word list to assist segmentation) which takes 12+ seconds. I was wondering if it is possible to speed up the loading process, and more importantly, how to avoid loading it repeatedly when I need to call the python script multiple times?

Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
op = subprocess.Popen(['java',
                       '-mx2g',
                       '-cp',
                       'seg.jar',
                       'edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier',
                       '-sighanCorporaDict',
                       'data',
                       '-testFile',
                       filename, 
                       '-inputEncoding',
                       'utf-8', 
                       '-sighanPostProcessing',
                       'true',
                       'ctb', 
                       '-loadClassifier',
                       **'./data/ctb.gz',**
                       '-serDictionary',
                       './data/dict-chris6.ser.gz',
                       '0'],
                       stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                       stdin  = subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,
                       )
```

In the above code, './data/ctb.gz' is the place where the large word list file is loaded. I think this might be related to process, but I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the java program produces output as soon as it receives input from [`filename` named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9029282/4279) and you can't change the java program then you could keep your Python script running instead and communicate with it via files/sockets as [@DNA suggested for the Java process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9041679/4279) (the same idea but the Python program keeps running).

```
# ...
os.mkfifo(filename)

p = Popen([..., filename, ...], stdout=PIPE)
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
     while True:
         indata = read_input() # read text to segment from files/sockets, etc
         f.write(indata)
         # read response from java process
         outdata = p.stdout.readline()# you need to figure out when to stop reading
         write_output(outdata) # write response via files/sockets, etc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @J.F. Sebastian. This gives me a context of how to implement this in my code.

Comment: You mentioned I need to figure out when to stop reading. By that do you mean to stop the JVM or just figure out the end of the output from the segmenter. In other words, are you suggesting to create a Java daemon process and runs the segmenter at the background, persistently?

Comment: @aihaiyang: I mean "figure out the end of the output from the segmenter". Make the Python program work as a script first, you can daemonize it later.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use an OS specific solution here. Most modern Operating Systems have the ability to have a partition in memory. For example, in Linux you could do

```
 mkfs -q /dev/ram1 8192
 mkdir -p /ramcache
 mount /dev/ram1 /ramcache
```

Moving the file to that directory would greatly speed I/O

Answer (score 1):

There might be many ways to speed up the loading of the word list, but it depends on the details. If IO (disk read speed) is the bottleneck, then a simple way might be to zip the file and use a ZipInputStream to read it - but you would need to benchmark this.

To avoid multiple loading, you probably need to keep the Java process running, and communicate with it from Python via files or sockets, to send it commands, rather than actually launching the Java process each time from Python.

However, both of these require modifying the Java code.

Comment: Thank very much for your comments. Great to know that it's possible to avoid repeated loading. But since I don't know Java, I'm not sure if I could do this. Could you please give me some pointers or some examples for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a single instance of the JVM and use [named pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156) to allow the python script to communicate with the JVM. This will work assuming that the program executed by the JVM is stateless and responds on its stdout (and stderr perhaps) to requests arriving via its stdin.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I could see the general idea, but since I don't know Java. So I'm wondering can you pls give me some more help on how to run a single instance of the JVM, and how to communicate it from python?

Comment: Well, if the assumptions I mentioned are correct there is no need to modify the Java application, but just redirect its stdin/stdout/stderr to appropriate named pipes. The pipes can then be opened by the python process to communicate with the Java app.

Comment: I think the java application is just doing word segmentation, and most likely would be stateless. But I don't know Java, and don't know where to get started.

Comment: You don't need to know Java to apply this solution. You need to know named pipes which is why I have added a reference link :-) Just run your Java app normally as you would on the command-line with redirections to a named pipe. See also `mkfifo` command.

Comment: Thanks Adam, much appreciated. I think it's time for me to really have some working knowledge of Java in order to navigate through this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not track whether the file has already been read on the python side?  I'm not a python whiz, but I'm sure you could have some list or map/dictionary of all the files that have been opened so far.

Comment: Thanks @user949300. The wordlist file was compiled byte code and was loaded in Java. I'm not sure if I could open it in python, and then somehow send it over to Java...